# Why Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "propname", {.., value: fn} promotes fn to be a global variable?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, global

Hi recently i stumbbled upon this case and i have no clue whats going on:

Inside a self invoked anonymous function i have extended the Object Prototype as:

```js
(function () {

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "values", {
 configurable: false, 
 enumerable: false, 
 writable: false, 
 value: function () {
  var values = [];
  for (var k in this){
   values.push(this[k]);
  }
  return values;
 }
});
 
})();

console.log(window.values);
```

The problem is that the "values" function gets automatically promoted to global inside Firefox no matter what.

Can anybody explain why? and if its posible to extend the Object prototype without using the global scope?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> Can anybody explain why?

Because `Object.prototype` is in the prototype chain of `window`.

```js
console.log(window instanceof Object);
```

Therefore every property on `Object.prototype` is available as "global variable", e.g.

```js
console.log(window.toString === Object.prototype.toString);
```

This is *not* specific to Firefox btw.

> and if its posible to extend the Object prototype without using the global scope?

No. That's a side-effect of how `window` and the prototype chain works.

Because `Object.prototype` is part of almost every prototype chain, you should generally avoid extending it with non-standard methods.

Specifically regarding `values`: There is [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), which works similarly and is a standard method. Prefer to use/polyfill this one instead of adding things to `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Of course, just realised window is an object, silly question, thanks!.

Comment: @Mackraken The prototyping concept is not obvious to beginners and there will be many people looking for this issue. We have seen much more stupid questions on SO. Actually it is a good question. First of all it is reproducible and even well formatted to run in sandbox on the SO page.

Comment: @Mackraken One of the top rules in JavaScript is: *Do **not** extend the `Object.prototype`.* At least avoid it as far as possible since you run into many side effects. This is why the `Object` itself has functions like `defineProperty` to manipulate other objects rather than giving every object a prototype method to do this. Even primitives like strings, integers aso. actually are objects.

Comment: Yep, just realised of that one too, very dangerous while its relatively safe extending any other Object types. i would probably create a new dict object type to do these kind of things. Thanks again, very useful information.